# Link variables representing rows, with several inputbox

Tags: excel, vba, variables, inputbox

I have a macro with two input boxes.

I would like to do the following:
Using the first input box, enter a number.
Using the second input box, enter a second number.
Copy the rows related to the line numbers.

For example, the user enters the number 1 into the first input box and enters the number 2 into the second input box. I would like to copy the rows 1 and 2 simultaneously.
With my current macro row 12 is copied.

I think the problem comes from line: `Rows(Chosennumber & Chosennumber2).Copy`

```
Sub selectlinefiletemplat()
    Dim Chosennumber As Integer
    Dim Chosennumber2 As Integer

    On Error GoTo NothingChosen

    Chosennumber = Application.InputBox( _
      prompt:="Type in a number", _
      Default:="Type your number here", _
      Type:=1)

    Chosennumber2 = Application.InputBox( _
      prompt:="Type in a number", _
      Default:="Type your number here", _
      Type:=1)

    Rows(Chosennumber & Chosennumber2).Copy

    Exit Sub

    NothingChosen:
        MsgBox "You didn't choose anything!"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `Application.Union`:

```
Application.Union(Rows(Chosennumber), Rows(Chosennumber2)).Copy
```

You doing it wrong because `&` concatenates string, so when you enter 1 and 2, concatenation is 12 :)

Comment: But `Chosennumber` and `Chosennumber2` aren't ranges, so you'll need `Union(Rows(Chosennumber), Rows(Chosennumber2)).Copy`. Note to OP: You should qualify the sheet you want the procedure performed on, like: `Sheet1.Rows(Chosennumber)`

Comment: @M.Schalk That's what I meant... Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you very Michat Turczyn and M.Schalk, it is true as my 2 inputbox work with number, the solution Union(Rows(Chosennumber), Rows(Chosennumber2)).Copy works very well...

Comment: @Xavi If answer has helped you, you should accept it (green check mark on the left) and opitionally upvote :)